# why three-way interaction is not significant

Tags: anova, interaction

I have two-way interaction on the two levels of the third categorical variable, the pattern looks different, why is three-way interaction non-significant?[image]

Thanks to all!

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate since it has already been asked by the OP and although this answer is (IMHO) better the other one is older. Feel free to close the other one instead if that is the preferred solution.

Comment: It is more natural to close the other one as duplicate than this which have the better answer. Please go there to vote! (I started)